# Basic RAII spinlock class

Tags: c++, thread-safety, locking, atomic

I have written the following class that acts as a simple lock for mutual exclusion:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <fmt/core.h>

namespace util
{

class [[ nodiscard ]] spinlock
{
public:
    using lockable_type = std::atomic_flag;

    [[ nodiscard ]] explicit
    spinlock( lockable_type& lockable ) noexcept
    : m_lockable { lockable }
    {
        while ( m_lockable.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) )
        {
            while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) );
        }
    }

    spinlock( const spinlock& ) noexcept = delete;
    spinlock& operator=( const spinlock& ) noexcept = delete;

    ~spinlock( ) noexcept
    {
        m_lockable.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    }

private:
    lockable_type& m_lockable;
};

}


void func( const int value, std::vector<int>& vec, std::atomic_flag& flag )
{
    for ( auto count { 0uz }; count < 5; ++count )
    {
        const util::spinlock lock { flag };
        vec.emplace_back( count + static_cast<decltype( count )>( value ) );
    }
}

int main( )
{
    std::atomic_flag flag { };
    std::vector<int> result;

    {
    std::array<std::jthread, 3> threads { };
    auto& [ first_thread, second_thread, third_thread ] { threads };

    first_thread  = std::jthread { func, 0, std::ref( result ), std::ref( flag ) };
    second_thread = std::jthread { func, 5, std::ref( result ), std::ref( flag ) };
    third_thread  = std::jthread { func, 10, std::ref( result ), std::ref( flag ) };
    }

    for ( auto&& elem : result )
        fmt::print( "{}\n", elem );
}
```

Is the above program ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/rvMPh6W1r)) correct (in terms of race conditions, etc)? How good/bad is the design of the `spinlock` class? What could be improved here? It seems to work fine though.

The design of the class is similar to `std::lock_guard` but operates on the `std::atomic_flag` instead of a mutex type. It does not support copying/moving. And the constructor and the destructor are marked as `noexcept`.

Also would be better if `while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) );` had a body like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);` in order to reduce the load on the CPU? If so then how should it be implemented so that it depends on the client's choice whether they want to have sleeps in between calls to `test` or not and the amount of sleeping?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of creating your own [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)-style class that works on a `std::atomic_flag`, consider creating a class that wraps the `std::atomic_flag` but provides `lock()` and `unlock()` member functions. This would allow `std::lock_guard` to work with your spinlock class. Even better, other standard functions and classes like `std::lock()`, `std::unique_lock` and `std::scoped_lock` would then also work with your class.

Another benefit would be safety: a `std::atomic_flag` variable itself doesn't look like a lock. The compiler doesn't warn you if something sets or clears the flag when it shouldn't. By wrapping it in a type to make it look and behave like a [*BasicLockable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable), there is less chance of making mistakes in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a cool idea. I'll have to try it.

Comment: I just wrote this wrapper class and it works with a `std::lock_guard`. But I'm not sure about its name. What would you suggest as a name for this class that wraps a `std::atomic_flag` and acts like a lockable? Maybe `spinlock_mutex`? Or `atomic_mutex`? Or ...?

Comment: I would just name it `spinlock`. Consider creating a new question here on Code Review with your wrapper class so we can review it. Perhaps along with the code that is going to use it?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm planning to do. But the code is a bit lengthy so I need to create a minimal example that shows the usage.

Comment: We don't mind lengthy code at Code Review (of course it still needs to fit within the limits for this site).

Comment: oooh. I like this idea.

Answer (score 7):

I shiver whenever I see a spin lock.

**BUT** they are exceedingly cheap **IF** there is usually no contention. So if you need to guarantee something is only accessed by one thread and there are very low risk of multiple threads heading towards the lock (and usually if the task inside the lock is cheap), then this can be a good solution.

> Also would be better if while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) ); had a body

YES. A simple empty one is better than a semicolon.

```
while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) ) {
    // Body deliberately empty
}
```

> std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration); in order to reduce the load on the CPU?

No. Because that implies there is some load here and thus you have violated the rule on good places to use spin locks. At this point you may as well switch to a mutex.

> How good/bad is the design of the spinlock class?

I can't see a problem. So as spin locks go it seems to work. If spin locks are a good idea depends a lot.

> What could be improved here?

The ability to take multiple locks.
But don't do the thing of simply locking them in the order provided by the caller (that leads to deadlocks). You need to be able to lock them in a unique order that is repeatable whatever instance of `spinlock` is used (its an interesting problem to solve :-)

---

My main issue with spin locks is not the lock themselves. But the code that surrounds them. It is way to easy to change the behaver of surrounding code so that using a spin lock becomes a bad idea rather than a good one, and there is no automated way of the compiler telling you that your invariant of low contention still holds.

But that is not a comment on your code just a general one on spin locks.

Comment: Mutexes are also very cheap if there is no contention; just a compare-and-exchange instruction. And when there is contention, it really depends on the situation whether a mutex or a spinlock is more efficient.

Comment: "*something is only accessed by one thread and there are very low risk of multiple threads heading towards the lock (and usually if the task inside the lock is cheap), then this can be a good solution.*" Yeah I think this is the exact scenario that I have in a few parts of my program so I guess it's a good decision to use a spinlock there.

Comment: Those places are inside the body of the catch blocks. Whenever an exception is thrown inside a thread function (which happens pretty rarely) the catch clause catches it and then tries to lock the atomic_flag by constructing a `util::spinlock`. Then it emplaces back the `std::exception_ptr` object into the global `std::vector<std::exception_ptr>`  and then calls `stop_source.request_stop()` and then exits the scope of the catch block (which means the lock is released). So only two small statements are executed when the flag is locked. Do you think this a good place to use `spinlock`?

Comment: The locking is done on the vector since if another exception is thrown in another thread then it can't push it to the vector and has to wait for the lock to be released by the first thread.

Comment: @digito_evo It might be better to post a new question so we can review the code where the spinlock is used.

Comment: For empty-body spin-loops, I find `while(...){}` is idiomatic and easy to read.  The `{}` makes it stand out as much as necessary.  And the lack of indentation on the next line is enough hint to draw your eye to the `{}` instead of `;` at the end of that line if you see the `while` and are looking for the body.  (If the condition itself is very long, then yeah putting the `}` on the next line makes sense.)

Answer (score 1):

### This Busy-Waits

You might prefer to idle-wait, such as with `std::this_thread::yield();`.  When there is contention, that allows other threads to make progress.

You would not want to put the thread to sleep for an interval.  Let the scheduler do its job.  However, there are some lighter-weight options available on different CPUs.  I’ve seen the `pause` instruction used on x86 (which is designed for this, especially on processors with hyperthreading, to let the core run more efficiently on its other thread) and `yield` instruction on ARM.  Another common approach is to do something lightweight, like `pause` or a memory barrier, the first few times a thread is locked out, in the hope that the lock will be available momentarily, and switch to `yield` if it turns out the other critical section is running for a significant amount of time.