# atomic spinlock mutex class

Tags: c++, error-handling, concurrency, c++20, atomic

This here is the follow-up to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284526/basic-raii-spinlock-class#284526). I was recommended to implement a [*Lockable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Lockable) type (similar to `std::mutex`) that can work with `std::lock_guard`, `std::scoped_lock`, etc. instead of unnecessarily writing a class similar to `std::lock_guard` (thus violating D.R.Y). The result is a class named `spinlock_mutex`. The below example snippet is very similar to what I'm trying to do in my multithreaded program.

The new MRE ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/KoPf6b95v)):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <stop_token>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <exception>
#include <fmt/core.h>

namespace util
{

class [[ nodiscard ]] spinlock_mutex
{
public:
    using lockable_type = std::atomic_flag;

    [[ nodiscard ]] constexpr
    spinlock_mutex( ) noexcept = default;

    spinlock_mutex( const spinlock_mutex& ) noexcept = delete;
    spinlock_mutex& operator=( const spinlock_mutex& ) noexcept = delete;

    void lock( ) noexcept
    {
        while ( m_lockable.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) )
        {
            while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) ) { }
        }
    }

    bool try_lock( ) noexcept
    {
        return m_lockable.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    }

    void unlock( ) noexcept
    {
        m_lockable.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    }

private:
    lockable_type m_lockable { };
};

}


constinit util::spinlock_mutex mtx { };
constinit std::vector<std::exception_ptr> caught_exceptions { };

void func( const std::stop_source stop_src, const int base_value ) noexcept
{
    for ( auto counter { 0uz }; !stop_src.stop_requested( ) && counter < 3; ++counter )
    {
        try
        {
            fmt::print( "base value: {} --- {}\n",
                        base_value, counter + static_cast<decltype( counter )>( base_value ) );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            stop_src.request_stop( );
            const std::lock_guard lock { mtx };
            caught_exceptions.emplace_back( std::current_exception( ) );
        }
    }
}

int main( )
{
    { // a scope to limit the lifetime of jthread objects

    std::stop_source stop_src { std::nostopstate };
    std::array<std::jthread, 8> threads { };

    try
    {
        stop_src = std::stop_source { };

        for ( auto value { 0 }; auto& thrd : threads )
        {
            thrd = std::jthread { func, stop_src, value };
            value += 5;
        }
    }
    catch ( const std::exception& ex )
    {
        stop_src.request_stop( );
        fmt::print( "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
    }

    }

    for ( const auto& ex_ptr : caught_exceptions )
    {
        if ( ex_ptr != nullptr )
        {
            try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception( ex_ptr );
            }
            catch ( const std::exception& ex )
            {
                fmt::print( "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I may have to mention that my aim is to inform the threads to return whenever an exception is caught in one thread. This is done using the copies of `std::stop_source` that are passed to each thread.

So the `constinit util::spinlock_mutex mtx { };` will only need to be locked pretty rarely since exceptions are thrown rarely. Is this a valid case to use a spinlock?

With that said, do the above program and its flow control make any sense? I have thought about what could go wrong (e.g. deadlocks, uncaught exceptions, etc.) but nothing worrying caught my attention.

The last *for* loop is there to handle the exceptions after all the `std::jthread`s have been destructed. That's also why the `jthread`s are declared in an inner scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No need to explicitly delete the copy constructor

There is no need to delete the copy constructor and copy assignment operators. Since `std::atomic_flag` itself is non-copyable, your class will by default also be non-copyable.

## Consider making `try_lock()` `[[nodiscard]]`

You made the class and the constructor itself `[[nodiscard]]`, but it might make sense to apply this to `try_lock()` as well.

## Use `std::mutex` unless you have a very good reason not to

While the spinlock class itself looks fine, I don't see why you would need to use a spinlock specifically for the use case you have. A `std::mutex` would do fine. Consider that exceptions will be on the slow path, the potential overhead of `std::mutex` is not something I would worry about at all.

Also consider that adding something to a `std::vector` can take a long time, especially if the vector needs to grow its storage. This will mean allocating new memory and copying the old contents over. With a `std::mutex`, other threads will be put to sleep while this happens. With your spinlock, those threads will waste a lot of CPU cycles.

Also consider that spinlocks work best if every logical thread is associated with its own hardware thread. If however the operating system decides to let two logical threads share the same hardware thread, it means that if one logical thread gets scheduled out while holding the spinlock, and another logical thread gets scheduled in that tries to lock the same spinlock, the second one will waste all of its time slice for nothing, whereas with a `std::mutex` this waste would not happen.

## Avoid locking altogether

Even better than optimizing the type of lock is to not need a lock. If you know you only have 8 threads, you can declare a `std::array` of 8 caught exceptions, and give each thread a pointer to their own element inside that array. This way they can write to it without needing a lock.

Comment: "*I don't see why you would need to use a spinlock specifically for the use case you have*" Exception safety. That's about it. I want the program to be safe. The `lock()` function of a `std::mutex` can throw inside the catch block. And that would lead to program termination. On the other hand, the `lock()` function of the above `spinlock_mutex` class is `noexcept`.

Comment: And speaking of adding items to a vector, I have come to the conclusion that no more than 8 `std::exception_ptr` instances will be added to the vector in the worst-case scenario (where every single thread throws an exception and then exits). So I think I can just add `caught_exceptions.reserve( std::size( threads ) );` so that it never reallocates.

Comment: Throwing inside a catch block does not lead to program termination, that second exception can be caught in a catch block at a different layer. While I agree it's best not to have your error handling code cause any errors, consider that when calling `lock()` on a `std::mutex` will normally only throw if error checking is enabled and you are locking the same mutex twice in the same thread for example (which is good, your spinlock class does not detect such errors and will just deadlock).

Comment: As for reserving size up front, consider that this is supposed to be something that only happens in a very exceptional case. By reserving space, you are paying the cost of the allocation regardless of whether an error occurs. If it's only once for the whole program, that's probably fine, but if the vector of caught exceptions would be something declared inside a function body that is called multiple times, I would advise against it. Finally, if you know the size up front anyway, you can just assign one element of the vector to each thread, so they can write to it without needing a lock at all.

Comment: Is there any chance of a deadlock happening in the above program due to that problem?

Comment: I don't see a potential deadlock in your program, it looks fine!

Comment: You are right. There was no need for a lock in this case at all. I applied your suggestion using a stack-allocated `std::array` and passed each element by reference to its associated thread. It's less complicated now. And definitely safer too!

Comment: Even if std::atomic_flag causes the class to be non-copyable, as a user of the class I believe that having a copy constructor deleted more clearly shows the intent, and may give better diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final version of my `spinlock_mutex` class:

```
class [[ nodiscard ]] spinlock_mutex
{
public:
    using lockable_type = std::atomic_flag;

    [[ nodiscard ]] constexpr
    spinlock_mutex( ) noexcept = default;

    void
    lock( ) noexcept
    {
        while ( m_lockable.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) )
        {
            while ( m_lockable.test( std::memory_order_relaxed ) ) { }
        }
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] bool
    try_lock( ) noexcept
    {
        return m_lockable.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire );
    }

    void
    unlock( ) noexcept
    {
        m_lockable.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    }

private:
    lockable_type m_lockable { };
};
```

It's not perfect but it can be useful in some cases.